# Pass String Parameter into Class/Function (Python)

Tags: python

If I have a class as such:

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

I can create an object by:

```
temp = Sample(a=100,b=100,c=100)
```

But what if I have:

```
my_str = "a=100,b=100,c=100"
```

How can I `temp = Sample(my_str)` properly?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Where do you get that string?

Comment: you might need to parse it in another constructor

Comment: propose : change `__init__` to `__init__(self , **kwds)

Comment: Some of these answers are recommending to use `eval`. While it is simple, [there are reasons why `eval` is discouraged.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: `eval` is a to use , no for avoiding! it has proplems but when need must use it ,

Answer (score 4):

You can parse and eval the string like:

#### Code:

```
@classmethod
def from_str(cls, a_str):
    return cls(**eval("dict({})".format(a_str)))
```

#### Test Code:

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, a_str):
        return cls(**eval("dict({})".format(a_str)))

x = Sample.from_str("a=100,b=100,c=100")
print(x.a)
```

#### Results:

```
100
```

Comment: How about `ast.literal_eval` instead?  I guess formatting it to a dict is ok too.

Comment: @pylang [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can't handle operators (like `=`). `ast.literal_eval('a=100')` raises `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Answer (score 1):

use `eval`

```
temp = eval("Sample("+my_str+")")
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it is definitely an option, using [`eval` can be dangerous](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/7xr839/after_the_recent_pybitmessage_exploit_let_us_all/). Here is an option which is [@StephenRauch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7311767/stephen-rauch)'s code just without using `eval`.

```
>>> class Sample:
...     def __init__(self, a, b, c):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
...         self.c = c
... 
...     @classmethod
...     def from_str(cls, a_str):
...         result = {}
...         for kv in a_str.split(','):
...             k, v = kv.split('=')
...             result[k] = int(v)
...         return cls(**result)
... 
>>> x = Sample.from_str('a=100,b=100,c=100')
>>> x.a
100
>>> type(x.a)
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = int(a)
        self.b = int(b)
        self.c = int(c)

mystr = "a=100,b=100,c=100"
temp = Sample(mystr.split(",")[0].split("=")[1],mystr.split(",")[1].split("=")[1],mystr.split(",")[2].split("=")[1])
print(temp.a)
print(temp.b)
print(temp.c)
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/NotedGrubbyProspect)

Comment: I don't understand the negative voting for my answer.

Comment: me too, yours and below ones same I guess - imma upvote you buddy

Comment: @AnkushRathi Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
my_str = "a=100,b=100,c=100"                                                                                         

temp = Sample(int(my_str.split(',')[0].split('=')[1]),
               int(my_str.split(',')[1].split('=')[1]),
               int(my_str.split(',')[2].split('=')[1]))

print(temp.a)
# prints 100

print(temp.b)
# prints 100

print(temp.c)
# prints 100
```

Comment: Shouldn't `temp.a == 100` and not `temp.a == 'a=100'`?

Comment: But isn't it supposed to be an integer? You are returning `'100'` vs `100`

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Thanks for the comment, edited it again :)  How does it look now?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put
temp = Sample(100,100,100)
the class will automatically interpret

```
a = 100
b = 100
c= 100
```